# How to get distinct filenames with different dates in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, stored-functions

I have a table with columns filename, projectname and recordinserttime. I want to get the distinct file names in a way that it checks for the first 5 numbers and matches it with other filenames to check for duplicates. If duplicates are present then it will just get the filename once for that file for the same project with the latest date on it.

Example 1:
What I am getting now is both the files which are the same so present as duplicates as you can see that both files are inserted on different dates with filename having first 5 digits as same in the filename.

```
**Filename**                **Projectname**       **RecordInsertTime**
12345_abcde_mnopqrst          Project1              08/10/2020
12345_abcde_rtyusety          Project1              08/12/2020
```

Example 2:

```
**Filename**                **Projectname**       **RecordInsertTime**
56789_fghijk_mnopqrst          Project1              08/10/2020
56789_fghijk_rtyusety          Project1              08/12/2020
```

Desired Output:
Desired output is to eliminate the duplicate and get the filename for the latest file (the file which has the latest record insert date on it) for the same project having duplicate filenames.

```
**Filename**                **Projectname**       **RecordInsertTime**
12345_abcde_mnopqrst          Project1              08/12/2020
```

My Code:

```
   Select replace(replace([FileName],'\\project\SSIS ReturnedReport(xyz)\',''),'.xlsx','') as FileName, ProjectName, cast(RecordInsertTime as DATE) as 'RecordInsertTime'from ReturnedFiles where ProjectName is not null
```

Thanks

Comment: More than 2 examples will help us help you here. Those 2 on there own can't demonstrate the full logic.

Comment: Do a GROUP BY, use HAVING.

Comment: @Larnu I have edited the quesiton by adding another example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of ways you could do this, but here is my approach. Get the maximum RecordInsertTime for what I am calling the FilenamePrefix and Projectname and then join back to the ReturnedFiles table to get the full details related to that maximum row.

```
CREATE TABLE ReturnedFiles
(
    Filename VARCHAR(25)
  , Projectname VARCHAR(25)
  , RecordInsertTime DATETIME
);

INSERT INTO ReturnedFiles
VALUES
  ('12345_abcde_mnopqrst', 'Project1', '08/10/2020')
, ('12345_abcde_rtyusety', 'Project1', '08/12/2020')
, ('56789_fghijk_mnopqrst', 'Project1', '08/10/2020')
, ('56789_fghijk_rtyusety', 'Project1', '08/12/2020');

SELECT
           rf.Filename
         , rf.Projectname
         , rf.RecordInsertTime
FROM       (
               SELECT
                        LEFT(Filename, 5)     AS [FilenamePrefix]
                      , Projectname
                      , MAX(RecordInsertTime) AS [MaxRecordInsertTime]
               FROM     ReturnedFiles
               GROUP BY LEFT(Filename, 5)
                      , Projectname
           )              x
INNER JOIN ReturnedFiles rf ON x.FilenamePrefix = LEFT(rf.Filename, 5)
                           AND x.Projectname = rf.Projectname
                           AND x.MaxRecordInsertTime = rf.RecordInsertTime;
```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=a67936f37abb56d221f751b5e0cdc917).

Comment: I have tried this on my code but it only shows one file for each of my projects where as I have 7 projects with around 600 total files in it. But it works fine for your demo though I am not sure what I am missing here.

Comment: What I can see is that it is only returning one file for each project and that file is the one which has the max record insert time.

Comment: More comprehensive and representative data would help. With the additional two rows you added to the question is the result you have still what you are expecting?

Comment: after using your code what I am getting is like this:                                   **Filename**                **Projectname**       **RecordInsertTime**
56789_fghijk_mnopqrst        Project1              08/10/2020
11111_fghijk_rtyusety          Project2             08/12/2020                                                12345_fghijk_mnopqrst        Project3              08/10/2020
22222_fghijk_rtyusety          Project4              08/12/2020                                                   33333_fghijk_mnopqrst        Project5              08/10/2020

Comment: what I should get Should be like getting all the filenames for each projects

Comment: Please create insert statements with a set of data using [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/) (or something similar) and the expected output from that data.